# Div tag acting as buttons, and also Dynamic buttons like delete, report spam, etc

Tags: html, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

This is a practice test case where i have to login to gmail and click on all the checkbox in the dynamic web table and delete the mails. So i made the following code.

The problem is when i am checking the delete button is available or not. It is returning true but when i am trying to perform the delete operation it is displaying `ElementNotVisibleException`. FYI i am able to select all the checkboxes. Only issue is clicking on the buttons made from  tag.

```
//deleting mail by clicking on all checkbox     
int count = 1;     
List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath(cbox));   
System.out.println("Total number of checkboxes are \t: " +    lst.size());    
for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){         
  WebElement wwe = lst.get(i);  
  wwe.click(); 
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
  System.out.println("Checked on checkbox number \t: " + count); 
  count++; 
} 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
try{ 
  boolean flag = driver.findElement(By.xpath(delete)).isEnabled(); 
  if(flag){ 
    System.out.println("\nDelete button is enabled"); 
  }else{ 
    System.out.println("\nDelete button is not enabled"); 
  } 
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(delete)).click(); 
}catch(Throwable t){ 
  System.out.println("\nUnable to locate delete button"); 
  System.out.println("The exception occuring is \t: " + t); 
}
```

Comment: what's the xpath you've used for delete

Comment: String cbox = "//table[@class='F cf zt']//div[@class='T-Jo-auh']";
  String delete = "//div[@class='asa']/div[@class='ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji']";

Comment: String cbox = "//table[@class='F cf zt']//div[@class='T-Jo-auh']";  
  String delete = "//div[@class='asa']/div[@class='ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji']";  
This is the xpath

Comment: add those in question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following and it worked fine.You just have to add enough wait

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60 /*timeOut in Seconds*/);
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd"))).sendKeys("xxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    String cbox = "//table[@class='F cf zt']//div[@class='T-Jo-auh']";
    String delete = "//div[@class='asa']/div[@class='ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji']";

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(cbox)));

    int count = 1;
    List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath(cbox));
    System.out.println("Total number of checkboxes are \t: " + lst.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        WebElement wwe = lst.get(i);
        wwe.click();
        System.out.println("Checked on checkbox number \t: " + count);
        count++;
    }

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(delete))).click();
    try {
        WebElement deleteButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(delete));
        boolean flag = deleteButton.isEnabled();
        if (flag) {
            System.out.println("\nDelete button is enabled");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nDelete button is not enabled");
        }
        deleteButton.click();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("\nUnable to locate delete button");
        System.out.println("The exception occuring is \t: " + t);
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me too. It was helpful. I got the idea also for future similar problems. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: By the way you seem to be a naruto fan. me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably chose not so automation friendly web app like Gmail to start with. I believe they have deliberately developed Gmail client side in such a way that its harder for a Robot to perform actions.

As for your question, I think the delete button appears a little after check boxes are clicked. So I believe you will have to explicitly wait for the button to appear. It's also possible that your xpath is not correct.

You could try this,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60 /*timeOut in Seconds*/);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
visibilityOfElementLocated(By.css("div[data-tooltip='Delete']"))).click();
```

Comment: i have tried that also before posting this question and i am checking all the checkbox one by one. so there is a lot of time even after the delete button is appeared. but the problem is that clicking on buttons made from div tag.

Comment: i tried a code where i login to gmail, then click on compose button, then enter the details of TO address, subject & some message in the message textbox. but when i clicked on the send button it threw an exception.

Comment: my main problem is buttons created from div tag

Comment: Like I eluded in my answer. Gmail is a tough nut and not supposed to be used by robots. I think you have learnt enough in this exercise to move on to a different app that's meant to be automated for testing.

Comment: But then that is the challenge here. If i can crack how to automate it then the rest would be easy. I already find other websites easy to automate. Although i am still in the learning phase. If there is a solution please help me out. Thanks

Comment: I shouldn't have said tough nut, rather again it's not the right app to automate. All attributes are dynamically generated and you can't assure if it will stay the same the next time. In automation there are other challenges like selecting right selectors, scalability, maintenance in long run etc. you can start learning those aspects

Comment: That said I'll look at your problem in detail. But the point is that it's not worth spending time on automating gmail since things are just NOT going to work because Gmail is not meant for such purposes