# Unable to click on Setting Icon in Gmail with selenium web-driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is what i am trying do on Gmail.

1. www.gmail.com
2. Login using a valid user (if does not exist create a dummy user)
3. Click on Inbox
4. Click on first email
5. Click on Compose Email.
6. Send the mail to the same email account.
7. Click on options icon on the top right corner
8. Got to vacation responder on the General settings tab
9. Select vacation responder to on.

I am able to click on 1st email and pick the email Address and then click on compose email button, also able to send the email.
The problem i am facing is unable to click on settings icon. The element is hidden, i am not able to click it. I tried it with customized-Xpath and also tried to click it with coordinates.
But it not working for me. Please can anyone help me on this.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


    public class Gmail1 {   

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            // Login to browser
            WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            System.out.println("Browser opned");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("Use your UserId");
            System.out.println("Entered Email id");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='next']")).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on Next");
               Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("Use your password");
            System.out.println("Entered the Password");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signIn']")).click();
            System.out.println("Welcome to gmail");
               Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':3d']")).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on email");
               Thread.sleep(3000);
            String emailid = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='go']")).getText();
            emailid=emailid.substring(emailid.indexOf("<")+1, emailid.indexOf(">"));
            System.out.println(emailid);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':it']/div/div")).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on Compose mail");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='to']")).sendKeys(emailid);
            System.out.println("Entered the TO Email Address");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='subjectbox']")).sendKeys("My Mail");
            System.out.println("Entered Subject of the email");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='button' and .='Send']")).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on send button");

            clickSetting(driver);    
        }
    public static void clickSetting(WebDriver driver){
            //Tried with Coordinates (doesn't work)
            Point point = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='G-Ni J-J5-Ji'] [@gh ='s']/*[1]")).getLocation();
            System.out.println(point.x + "-" + point.y);
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
            builder.moveByOffset(point.x, point.y).click().build().perform(); //Getting Error.

            //Tried with Action Class (doesn't work)
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            WebElement SettingWheel=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-tooltip='Settings' and @role='button']"));
            WebElement SettingsLink=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='menuitem']/div[.='Settings']"));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(SettingWheel));
            Actions  actions  = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(SettingWheel).moveToElement(SettingsLink).click().build().perform();//Getting Error.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Clicked On Setting");           
        }
```

*Error message*:- "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Go for another website. Stay away from google

Comment: I don't have an option to try it in other website. I need to do it in gmail only. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
public static void clickSetting(WebDriver driver){
           List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@gh='s']/*[@role='button']"));
        for(WebElement element:elements){
            if(element.isDisplayed()){
                element.click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ms']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }          
        }
```

Comment: Settings icon has 2 nodes identified by your xpath, one is visible and another is invisible and both were present in DOM. You were trying to click invisible element since it appears first; hence, you were getting "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted..." exception. So above code will take both elements identified by your xpath and check whether its visible or not. If visible then click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your xpath. I tried with id ad it worked. `Thread.sleep` is bad idea. Don't go with that and instead use `WebDriverWait`

Anyhow the following snippet will click on settings gear then settings and wait till the Settings panel is loaded completely

Also go through this [Gmail  Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220604/div-tag-acting-as-buttons-and-also-dynamic-buttons-like-delete-report-spam-et/31230799#31230799) and see how I've handled Gmail login without Thread.sleep

```
public static void clickSetting(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=':3d']"))).click();
    System.out.println("Clicked On Settings Gear");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@role='menuitem']/div[.='Settings']"))).click();
    System.out.println("Clicked On Setting");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='dt']")));
    System.out.println("Settings Visible");
}
```

Comment: Hi Madhan,
Thanks for sharing the code.
I have used the same code, you send it for gmail. But it is not working for me. 
   
Error Message:- Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id=':3d']
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
The scenario i am trying, You need to open the 1st email of your inbox. Then try to click on setting gear -> settings.

Comment: @Harikishen This code is for Clicking the Settings alone I haven't done anything for opening  1st email of inbox

Comment: Just to clarify. The same code will not work, when the 1st email of inbox is opened and you are trying to click on Settings gear. You will get the same error. That is the issue i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package yourPackageName;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestClass2 {
static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Step_1_LaunchApp();
    Step_2_LoginUsingCredentials();
    Step_3_ClickOnInbox();
    Step_4_ClickOnFirstEmail();
    Step_5_ClickOnComposeEmail();
    Step_6_ClickOnSettingsIcon();
}

private static void Step_6_ClickOnSettingsIcon() {
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='aos T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji']")).click();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void Step_5_ClickOnComposeEmail() {
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void Step_4_ClickOnFirstEmail() {
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='tabpanel'][1]//table//tr[1]")).click();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    waitTimeInSecond(2);
}

private static void Step_3_ClickOnInbox() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/a[contains(text(),'Inbox')]")).click();
    waitTimeInSecond(2);
}

private static void Step_2_LoginUsingCredentials() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    waitTimeInSecond(2);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("Password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    waitTimeInSecond(5);
}

private static void Step_1_LaunchApp() {
    driver.get("http://gmail.com");
}

public static void waitTimeInSecond(int waitTime){
    try{Thread.sleep(waitTime*1000);}catch(Exception e){}
   }
}
```

.

Put your credentials first and run the script, it will click on settings gear.