# Selenium: sendKeys()

Tags: java, python, selenium

I tried using Java + Selenium to automatically login to my Gmail account however each time I am blocked by Google. When I log in manually (even on the very same server) I have no such issue. Further, if I use "sendKeys" type lib (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys/0.3) I have no such problem.

My question is two fold:

1. What are the tech differences between how Selenium "sends keys" and how a normal user would? Or how the Python library does?
2. Is there a way to modify selenium so it mimics a real user? Or is there another library to use instead of Selenium that mimicks a real user?

Thanks

Comment: Share your code you have written to login in gmail. It should work..

Comment: Have you checked this out [For Gmail login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220604/div-tag-acting-as-buttons-and-also-dynamic-buttons-like-delete-report-spam-et/31230799#31230799)

Answer (score 1):

Actually its the difference of speed. Human being types slowly and script write it very fastly. So, you have to decrease your script speed. So on the whole you have to built better bot.
Better bots are not going to be detected by any server.

Answer (score 0):

You should include some delay in your code to cheat google that your code is real human - that's it :)  `Thread.sleep` could be the easiest solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Open gmail & login & open latest received mail

```
DriverObj.get("http://www.gmail.com");
                DriverObj.findElement(By.id("gmail-sign-in")).click();
                DriverObj.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("youremailID");
                DriverObj.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
                DriverObj.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("yourpassword");
                DriverObj.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            WebElement tableelement=DriverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody"));
            java.util.List<WebElement> tableelement1=tableelement.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody/tr"));
            int tableelementsize=tableelement1.size();
            int i;
            if(tableelementsize>0){
                //DriverObj.navigate().refresh();
                for(i=0;i<tableelementsize;i++){
                    DriverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody/tr/td[6]")).click();
                }

            }else {
                 if(tableelementsize==0){
                    DriverObj.navigate().refresh();
                    for(i=0;i<tableelementsize;i++){
                        DriverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody/tr/td[6]")).click();
                    }
                }
```

path of mail box might be change (you have need to change according to your work)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1st question : 
Sendkeys() method refers to user input to a particular text box on the web page where as we can also use javascriptExecuter for the same operation.

Answer to 2nd question :
As per my knowledge NO. but I am not so sure about it.

In Java use the following code to log in to Gmail.

However I can say after clicking on sign in button the Inbox page takes time to load (at around 10 seconds max)

So in time being if you are searching for another element without any wait (implicit or explicit) then it will throw error.

driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("userName");

driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("password");

driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

Then you can use Thread.sleep(10000) or if you have written any wait method to make the driver wait for the next object to be visible , You can use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, Selenium just provides library to write automated test scripts. If you wanted to act as a human. Then you should add some wait statement in between your test steps into entire script. Until you didn't add any wait in script, it will behave like a robotic test only. If you take any examples of test automation tool, tool doesn't add any extra information/action towards automation testing.Thats what automated testing is... It's not automatic testing. It's just computer aided testing done by machine. I hope now you'll be more clear with above example.

Comment: Hello @vishal8 can you explain more about your solution? Also try to include websites as source or reference and some code if needed.

Comment: Hi @0rkan I don't think so any links or demo code is required to elaborate above questions. I have added some key point which is very useful to understand about selenium test execution.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is send a wrong e-mail as first attempt, after the error message, you could apply the right e-mail, this is an human action.